# Can't restore mavericks backups in time machine

Tags: time-machine

I'm trying to restore a time machine backup onto a new machine, however the only options are backups done prior to mavericks. The backups done under mavericks don't come up but I am sure they are on my external hard drive.

Comment: If you browse the time machine drive manually, do you see backups that should contain mavericks?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you're also running Mavericks on the new machine. If it's a new machine from Apple, this is a given, but please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Having similar problem.  After several calls regarding a slow iMac, I was told to erase the main disk and restore from my back ups.  Last backup was in Sept which I recall was when I upgraded to Mavericks.  My Time Machine disk does have my very latest backup its just the recovery process can't see it!

The solution I've been given is:

1. Do latest restore possible (last Mountain Lion backup)
2. Install OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)
3. Copy latest user folder from time machine and replace the current user folder to recover the latest documents and files.

Not ideal and takes a long time!

Comment: And did it work for you?

Comment: Not sure if it worked for this user, but experience tells me that just copying the folder doesn't work. Time Machine intelligently (supposedly) backs up only the files that have changed. Say you modify a document in October and regularly back up until August next year and never touch the document again in that time. If you copy your user folder from TM it won't have your document.